# Joomla 3.x PHP compatability issue

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a hosting server with php version 5.2.10 ...

is there is any way to make joomla 3 application works with php5.2.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation states that for running Joomla! 3.x the minimum required version of PHP is 5.3.1: [source](http://docs.joomla.org/Technical_requirements). Personally I believe that's plenty of reason to believe it's actually needed, as it is stated as a minimum.

And even if there is some hackish way to be able to use Joomla! 3.x using PHP 5.2.x, I would highly disrecommend it regardless of how well it's done. You don't want to tinker around with core code, which probably would be necessary then.

Comment: It's not just the core code but also many of the extensions which rely on a minimum of PHP 5.3.